# Automated software testing on real hardware

Tags: windows, deployment, automation, automated-testing

I'm currently working on a small testing farm at work and especially the part of resetting the machines after a test was run gives me some headaches.
Before we decided to get a couple of dedicated test machines with different hardware configurations the plan was to run the tests on a single machines using Hyper-V so cleaning up afterwards was just a matter of deleting the actual VM.
Unfortunately resetting a complete machine is a bit more expensive in terms of time and I guess also in terms of hardware weart out over the years if you do it often enough.

I believe that simply deinstalling the installed software won't be sufficient as there might be some files / redistributables left on the system which make subsequent test runs less useful.
I also believe that running Hyper-V VMs on the test machines would adversely affect the test results, especially on the weaker hardware configurations.

I really would like to know if there are some existing solutions to this problem and what would be the smartest way to do this.

Comment: You don't say what the test machine OS is, but for Windows client OS (7,8,10) you might just use the built in Reset/Refresh option. For a server OS you might look at using an imaging tool to create a standard image and use that to restore the machine after each test run.

Comment: Is there something special about the software being tested that _requires_ it to run on bare metal? If not, then just use VMs.

Answer (score 6):

You can absolutely use a set of VMs based on some “golden image” + differentials, and you can discard these over the time increments when / if needed. This is PowerShell scriptable (turn VM off, discard diffs and so on) and you can use Chef / Ansible for some higher level of automation as well. Alternative way would be using Veeam Community Edition which can do the same even w/out OS snapshots. It’s PowerShell scriptable of course, so automation is again easy to implement.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to boot from VHD, create an OS base install with everything you need configured and installed. Make a copy of the VHDX. Then run your tests and replace the "dirty" VHD with the backup copy and start over. You can automate some of this as well.

Answer (score 1):

I recently learned the [CloneZilla](http://clonezilla.org/) have this:

> Multicast is supported in Clonezilla SE, which is suitable for massive
>   clone. You can also remotely use it to save or restore a bunch of
>   computers if PXE and Wake-on-LAN are supported in your clients.

Answer (score -1):

> Unfortunately resetting a complete machine is a bit more expensive in terms of time and I
> guess also in terms of hardware weart out over the years if you do it
> often enough.

Nope. There is no reason your machine does not boot from a network via ISCSI, and then you are back to - Hyper-V style behavior (reset the image). Done, case closed.